# AngularJS v1.0.0 directive does not work in v1.0.7

Tags: angularjs

I created a directive using angularJS v1.0.0 and everything works fine, now I updated angular to v1.0.7 and my directive is not working any more, I tried many different ways to fix it but I couldn't make it work.

I tried to replace $beginRouteChange for $routeChangeStart and $afterRouteChange for $routeChangeSuccess and still not work

It is simply a text showing a "loading..." massage while the application is busy. You can see the explample in here:

http://mhevery.github.io/angular-phonecat/app/#/phones

Directive:

```
working version in AngularJS 1.0.0 but not in v1.0.7

'use strict';

/* Directives */

var directive = {};

directive.butterBar = function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $rootScope.$on('$beginRouteChange', function() {
        element.addClass('show');
        element.text('Loading...');
      });
      $rootScope.$on('$afterRouteChange', function() {
        element.removeClass('show');
        element.text('');
      });
    }
  };
};

angular.module('phonecatDirectives', []).directive(directive);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct events for catching route change are:

```
$routeChangeStart
$routeChangeSuccess
$routeChangeError
$routeUpdate
```

See [$route Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route)

Usage in your case:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    element.addClass('show');
    element.text('Loading...');
});
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    element.removeClass('show');
    element.text('');
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with catching route change? and how is related to my problem?

Comment: You are listening the wrong events, I've updated my answer to fit in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Umur I change the code and still not work: 
directive.butterBar = function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        element.addClass('show');
        element.text('Loading...');
      });
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        element.removeClass('show');
        element.text('');
      });
    }
  };
};

Answer (score 1):

Please check the docs: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route)

`$beginRouteChange` and `$afterRouteChange` are not supported.

Instead use `$routeChangeStart` and `$routeChangeSuccess`.